# How to Load File in html form from database using Laravel

Tags: laravel, file

I'm working with Laravel File System. I have done up-to File upload and show from database. Now, I'm facing problem when i'm try to update file in database. I can not load file in

`<input type="file" value="{{$file->name}}>"` this way, it's show null. How Can i do this stuff.
Here is my view part.

```
  <form class="" action="{{route('file.update',$file->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="file" name="image" value="{{$file->name}}">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="update">
  </form>
```

and Here is my Controller part.

```
  public function edit($id)
{
  $file=File::find($id);
  return view('uploads.edit',compact('file'));
}
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  return $request->file('image');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: Just remove the `image` field from the `$fillable` array of your model and put it in manually if it is set in the form.

Comment: I'm tried, it's not working.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't manually set the value of a file input field.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define value for

Usually in this case coders just show image or filelink to old file.

Comment: How can i do this ??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you may use Laravel Filestorage see documentations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem).